# Find the volume of the region inside both the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ and the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume, spherical-coordinates

> Find the volume of the region inside both the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ and the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$
>   $$2\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\frac{\pi} 6}\int_0^{2}1.r^2\sin \varphi dr d\varphi d\theta + \int_0^{2\pi}\int_{\frac{\pi} 6}^{\frac{5\pi} 6}\int_0^{\frac 1 {\sin \varphi}}1.r^2\sin \varphi dr d\varphi d\theta $$

This question is in the lecture notes but I didn't understand how the answer is obtained. Could someone help?

Comment: It is not the answer. It is just reduction of the problem to computation of integrals.  Hint: the intersection of the sphere and the cylinder are two circles lying in planes parallel to $(xy)$.

Comment: It seems that in you lectures the notations for $\varphi$ and $\theta$ are interchanged comparing to the standard ones. Besides the spherical coordinates are not well suited for computation of the cylinder volume.

Comment: @LeylaAlkan Yes sorry it is ok, I get confused because the convention for spherical coordinates are not always the same. I've added an answer let me know what exactly is not clear to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that

- the intersection of the cilinder and the sphere is for $z=\pm \sqrt 3$ that is $\varphi=\frac{\pi}6$ and $\varphi=\frac{5\pi}6$
- the first integral is twice the "ice cream" upper part of the sphere (in spherical coordinates)

[image]

- the second integral is the residual part inside the cylinder (in spherical coordinates)
- in the second integral $r(\varphi)=\frac1{\sin \varphi}$

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You obtain a spherical ring by drilling out a hole of the sphere with the cylinders radius.  It is well known that its volume solely depends on the height of the ring, namely $V=\frac{\pi}{6}h^3$, see [Remaining volume of a sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658004/remaining-volume-of-a-sphere/658215#658215).

Now subtract that volume from the volume of the sphere.  In our case $h=\sqrt3$, hence the volume we’re looking for is 
$$\frac43\pi\cdot2^3-\frac\pi6\sqrt{3}^3.$$